# Macro to Copy and SaveAs works fine on mac but not on pc

Tags: excel, vba, macos, file-format, save-as

I have a XLSM workbook with the code below which works perfectly on my mac but for my coworkers on pc's, the result is a document that can't be opened with excel and the file type is listed as File. It looks like this: [Text type doc with File extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfHZH.png)

Hoping someone smarter than me can help me figure out how to fix this.

```
Sub SaveAs()

    Dim workbook_Name As Variant

    workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename

    If workbook_Name <> False Then

         Worksheets("Staff Summary").Copy

         With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:=workbook_Name, FileFormat:=51
            .Close SaveChanges:=False

             Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you use a fixed name (including the file extension) does it work?  Does the file saved on the PC have an extension? (looks like it doesn't).  Windows relies on the extension to know what type of file it is.  Check the part about file extensions here:  https://software-solutions-online.com/excel-vba-save-file-dialog-getsaveasfilename/

Comment: From memory I don't think 51 is xlsm. Apple doesn't use extensions, which is why it works there. I think it's 52, but might be 54